# Manually installing a single component of a python package

Tags: python, pip

I installed a package lenstools(https://github.com/apetri/LensTools) using pip but seems like a sub-package is not installed.

From the code:

```
  from lenstools import ConvergenceMap 
  from lenstools.defaults import load_fits_default_convergence
```

I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-3ccb37a9fb55> in <module>
      1 from lenstools import ConvergenceMap
----> 2 from lenstools.defaults import load_fits_default_convergence

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lenstools.defaults'
```

there seems to be a problem in my installation process a couple of files were not installed. But I want to install them manually now. Like this file (lenstools.defaults) http://www.columbia.edu/~ap3020/LensTools/html/_modules/lenstools/defaults.html

Any help on how to install one component of a package manually using PIP or some other method?

Comment: It is not that `lentools.defaults` not installed yet, but rather you might be installing a different/old version of lenstools. Have you tried `pip install --upgrade lenstools`?

Comment: Yes I tried that, using the latest version. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Hmm ya I've tried and found the same error too

Comment: I suspect that it's the wrong path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `from lenstools.utils.defaults import load_fits_default_convergence` instead.

Seems like the documentation from columbia.edu is obsolete. I followed the 'https://lenstools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/lenstools/utils/defaults.html?highlight=default'.
[image: Screen Capture of the new docs]